# Expression Engine php framework

Tags: php, expressionengine

how to parse rss feed for latest news and read more this content in expression engine ?

I have done parse to rss feed but I need to whole content so I has to use read more button but when we click on this it redirect to another website but I need to direct on my site only.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feed is an xml file. To parse, and make changes in it you can use any xml library, for example:

[simpleXml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

You should also check [Xml Manipulation section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) in php docs

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Magpie plugin that comes with EE?

If that doesn't do everything you need have a look at the third party [Feed Parser](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser)